# Why doesn't my ord function work

Tags: haskell

I am pretty new to this language and I wrote this in Notepad and used it in ghci

```
import Data.Char
ord 'a'
```

In ghci it gives me this error

```
dayBefore.hs:2:1: error:
Parse error: module header, import declaration
or top-level declaration expected.
```

When I write this in ghci it works though???

Comment: You have a bare function call. A module can contain only definitions.

Comment: GHCi docs explain this, :load is for loading modules, as chepner says, you don't have a module, just a function call.  https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is saying that `ord 'a'` is not

1. A module header
2. An import declaration
3. A top-level declaration

It basically doesn't know what to do with the result of evaluating `ord 'a'`. It would be valid to write `foo = ord 'a'` and in `ghci` you can then write `foo` and get the result of the evaluation.